# '[NSString?]' does not have a member named 'componentsSeparatedByString'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My `var contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("")` is the bit of code that is throwing the error. Is it because I am using `NSString`? It's also not letting the code completion to work as it should.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var city: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var urlString = "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") + "/forecasts/latest"

        var url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data, response, error) in

            var urlContent = [NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)]
            var contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("")
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With brackets (`[` and `]`) you are creating an array. Just remove the `[]`. The following code should work. I have also unwrapped the optional string.

```
if let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
{
  let contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("")
}
```

Comment: I added a comment @Duncan

Comment: @Adam, you were missing braces around the conditional part of your if statement. I added them.

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets around that call are because you have been reading an Objective-C tutorial.

In swift you are creating an array.

Remove them.

The next bit is that the method creates an optional string. You need to unwrap it before you can use the string.

Read the swift book that is available for free from Apple. All of this is explained in there. You should read that before posting any more questions on SO as it will answer them all.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code & I am getting the message "expected '{ after 'if' condition with the `if let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` line of code. & I am getting "use of unresolved identifier 'urlContent'" after the `let contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("")` line of code.

Comment: Why are you posting a comment to FogMeister's answer about code suggested by somebody else? Go back and add a new section to your question, showing your new code and the errors that that new code generates. And Adam's code wasn't meant to be copy/paste ready. It's an outline of what yo need to do. (The statement after an if in Swift must be enclosed in braces. You need to add braces around the second line of that code.)

Comment: @DuncanC ok got it. Still new to this.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have told you, remove the square brackets.

The other bit of information is that the method you are using,

```
convenience init?(data data: NSData,
         encoding encoding: UInt)
```

Is a "failable" init method. You can tell by the question mark after the word init in its definition. That means that it might not work. Because of that, the result of the init method is an optional. Since it is an init for `NSString`, it's return type is Optional NSString, or `NSString?`.

You need to unwrap the optional. Adam's answer, uses `if let` syntax, which is called "optional binding." It saves the result of the right side of the expression into a new constant (`urlContent`) if it's non-nil, then runs the code after the if. If the right side of the expression **IS** nil the conditional code is skipped.